# Python Wikipedia API. Count function

Tags: python, wikipedia-api

I'm using Python library Wikipedia API to parse data from Wikipedia. I'm getting TypeError on count function.

Here is the code:

```
 import wikipedia

'Searching Wikipedia for List of Lexus vehicle

print ("1: Searching Wikipedia for 'List of Lexus vehicles'")
try:
    print (wikipedia.page('List of Lexus'))
    print ('-' * 60)
except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
    print (str(e))
    print ('+' * 60)
    print ('DisambiguationError: The page name is ambiguous')
print
```

Searching for Lexus vehicles:

```
print ("2: Searching Wikipedia for 'List of Lexus (vehicles)'")
print (wikipedia.page('List of Lexus_(vehicles)'))
print
```

Printing results:

```
 result = wikipedia.page('List of Lexus_(vehicles)').content.encode('UTF8')
    print ("3: Result of searching Wikipedia for 'List of Lexus vehicles_(vehicles)':")
    print (result)
    print
```

Count function:

```
 def lexus_count(vehicles):
        lexus_count = result.count(vehicles)
        print


    print ("The Wikipedia page for 'List of Lexus_(vehicles)' has " + \
        "{} occurrences of the word 'Lexus'".format(lexus_count()))
    print
```

Here is TypeError message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\College\Python\Labs\lab 3\kaminski_lab3_p2.py in <module>()
     30
     31 print ("The Wikipedia page for 'List of Lexus_(vehicles)' has " + \
---> 32     "{} occurrences of the word 'Lexus'".format(lexus_count()))
     33 print

TypeError: lexus_count() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vehicles'
```

Now I'm having new problem NameError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\College\Python\Labs\lab 3\kaminski_lab3_p2.py in <module>()
     30
     31 print ("The Wikipedia page for 'List of Lexus_(vehicles)' has " + \
---> 32     "{} occurrences of the word 'Lexus'".format(lexus_count(vehicles)))
     33 print

NameError: name 'vehicles' is not defined
```

Update not readable output part of the output:

```
The Wikipedia page for 'List of Lexus_(vehicles)' has <function lexus_count at 0x000002431D2B28C8> occurrences of the word 'Lexus'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lexus_count() takes argument vehicles and you forget to pass it to the function in line 32

Comment: Ok. Thank you now, I have new problem:

Comment: New error. Please look up I posted new code snippet.

Comment: i've just figured out function lexus_count is buggy
change it to be:

def lexus_count(vehicles):
    return result.count(vehicles)

Comment: Thank you, it did fix the problem but still, output information it's not readable. Please look for part of the output. I added to code part.

Comment: it seems you have printed the function itself not its return value, please write the edits you performed to code.